# How to add a static block in header next to logo in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created magento 2 custom theme and I need to add 2 static blocks next to logo . how can i achieve this . I'm tying show some html text in those blocks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this content in your **default.xml** here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.promotion.block.one" template="Magento_Theme::header/promo-block-1.phtml" after="logo"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.promotion.block.two" template="Magento_Theme::header/promo-block-2.phtml" after="header.promotion.block.one"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can create two template files here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/header/promo-block-1.phtml

Content for this file is :

```
<?php echo "Static Block Content - 1 "; ?>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/header/promo-block-2.phtml

Content for this file is :

```
<?php echo "Static Block Content - 2"; ?>
```

After this changes please clear cache and flush cache.

You can see this both blocks after your logo.

**Output :**
[image]

Hope this may help you! :)

Comment: Kishan it's working thank for the help.. appreciate it..